# Detecting iFrame's AJAX request submit from SWF. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, flash, get

I am trying to detect when a video has finished playing inside an iFrame. When it finishes, I can tell from the Firebug "Net" tab that it submits a GET request to a specific URL with a specific GET variable every time.

The video is a SWF object, so it's not submitting via jQuery or any other JavaScript framework.

Is there a way to listen for form requests submitted from within an iFrame?

```
<iframe id="videoScreen" width="944px" height="531px" src="http://video-site.com/video-location/video-name.swf" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and then when the video finishes, it sends out a GET request like:

```
GET http://video-site.com/showending?beacon=showending
```

As it is playing, it sends out GET requests to save the current position of the video like:

```
GET http://video-site.com/savePosition?position=1m3s&webpage=myWebSite.com%2Fmarketing-video.php
```

Thanks for looking!

Edit: Fixed the final URL to have the URL-encoded forward slash.

Comment: The Same Origin Policy prevents cross-domain scripting. You cannot do this without a browser plug-in.

Comment: @Diodeus, thank you for your answer.I am a web developer and will figure out how to create a browser plugin. I'm googling it now for how to do that, but do you have any recommendations for a particular framework that you've used in the past for that?

Comment: Sorry, never done it.